# How do I remove each N item in List until List.Count more than target value?

Tags: c#, list, linq, for-loop

There is a list of short. The values of it doesn't matter like:

```
List<short> resultTemp = new List<short>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...};
```

This code should reduse the result list count by removing each Nth item from it.

Example 1:

```
List<short>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}.Count == 10;
var targetItemsCount = 5;
```

result should be {1,3,5,7,9} and result.Count should be == 5

Example 2:

```
List<short>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}.Count == 9;
var targetItemsCo:nt = 3;
```

result should be {1,4,7} and result.Count should be == 3

But it should stop to remove it, somewhere for make result count equal targetItemsCount (42 in this code, but its value else doesn't matter).
The code is:

```
var currentItemsCount = resultTemp.Count;

var result = new List<short>();

var targetItemsCount = 42;
var counter = 0;
var counterResettable = 0;

if (targetItemsCount < currentItemsCount)
{
    var reduceIndex = (double)currentItemsCount / targetItemsCount;

    foreach (var item in resultTemp)
    {
        if (counterResettable < reduceIndex || 
            result.Count + 1 == currentItemsCount - counter)
        {
            result.Add(item);
            counterResettable++;
        }
        else
        {
            counterResettable = 0;
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

And the resault.Count in this example equals 41, but should be == targetItemsCount == 42;

Ho do I remove each N item in List untill List.Count more then target value with C#?

Comment: **Why** do you want to do this? When you debugged through it, why did it stop at 41 rather than 42?

Comment: So N is the `targetItemsCount`? instead of giving 3 possible input and respective output could you explain the algo, the step for lest say the first?

Comment: What if _targetItemsCount_ is larger than number of elements in the source list?

Comment: @xdtTransform There are 2 algs I should combine 1) I should to remove elements from list in case result list count more then targetItemsCount somehow. 2) I can do it by removing only first or last Nth items, but it will be more smooth result when I remove every Nth element.

Comment: @schlonzo It should remove nothing, "if" will be skipped.

Comment: I believe you have an rouding error in your logic - eg. your `reduceIndex` is `1.1` you will remove every second item everytime - but you never account for that the `reduceIndex` isn't `2` but only `0.1` larger than `1`.

Comment: @RandRandom it seems like you are right. I can't figure out the better algorhytm for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To guarantee you get the expected number of selected items:

```
double increment = Convert.ToDouble(resultTemp.Count) / targetItemsCount;

List<short> result = Enumerable.Range(0, targetItemsCount).
                                Select(x => resultTemp[(int)(x * increment)]).
                                ToList();
```

Note that in the following case

```
List<short>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}.Count == 9;
var targetItemsCount = 6;
```

The result will be `[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]`, i.e. rounding the index down when needed

Also, you'll need to add validation (`targetItemsCount > 0`, `targetItemsCount < resultTemp.Count`...)

[Link to Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GiCh14)

Comment: How dare you put `.` at the end of line instead of the start at the next new line.

Comment: @RandRandom So sue me

Comment: Like your solution and it fixes a problem mine has, but that misplaced `.` - that's just a No-Go and I will never up-vote a person who does that. *rage* ;)

Comment: @RandRandom check the fiddle with your solution https://dotnetfiddle.net/hqUThq vs 74's solution gets better spreding on {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} and targetItemsCount = 5. It's output 1 2 4 6 8 and yours gets 1 2 3 4 5. It doesn't mean, your bad or don't work, it works, but vc 74 a little better.

Comment: @mr_blond - thats the error I am talking about in my comment - I totally recommend his solution over mine, take it but don't copy his bad placement of `.` forget you ever had to see that

Comment: @RandRandom Okay))

Comment: @vc74 wow, I just noticed, thet this solution works well even for increasing the number of items! It makes 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 5 5 6 7 7 8 8 9 for 15. Yes, this is not the theme of curent question, but I needed increasing method too.

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct:

```
public static void run()
{
    var inputs =
        new List<Input>{
          new Input{ 
              Value = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },`
              TargetCount = 5, ExpectedOutput= new List<int>{1,3,5,7,9} 
          },
          new Input{  
              Value = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 },
              TargetCount = 3, ExpectedOutput= new List<int>{1,4,7} 
          },
        };

    foreach (var testInput in inputs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"# Input = [{string.Join(", ", testInput.Value)}]");
        var result = Reduce(testInput.Value, testInput.TargetCount);
        Console.WriteLine($"# Computed Result = [{string.Join(", ", result)} ]\n");
    }
}

static List<int> Reduce(List<int> input, int targetItemsCount)
{
    while (input.Count() > targetItemsCount)
    {
        var nIndex = input.Count() / targetItemsCount;
        input = input.Where((x, i) => i % nIndex == 0).ToList();
    }
    return input;
}

class Input
{
    public List<int> ExpectedOutput;
    public List<int> Value;
    public int TargetCount;
}
```

Result :

> Input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>    Computed Result = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9 ]
>
> Input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>    Computed Result = [1, 4, 7 ]

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
var resultTemp = Enumerable.Range(1, 9).ToList();
var targetItemsCount = 3;

var roundingError = resultTemp.Count % targetItemsCount;
var reduceIndex   = (resultTemp.Count - roundingError) / targetItemsCount;

List<int> result;
if (reduceIndex <= 1)
    result = resultTemp.Take(targetItemsCount).ToList();
else
    result = resultTemp.Where((a, index) => index % reduceIndex == 0).Take(targetItemsCount).ToList();
```

Tried it with your given example, also gave `42` a spin with a list of `1` to `100` it will remove every `2nd` item till it reaches `42`, so the last entry in the list would be `83`.

As I said, give it a try and let me know if it fits your requirement.